# Подскажите как сделать так чтобы при определенном результате$question['display_number'] менялось слово Question в title

Tags: php

```
    $feedback = $qra->view();
    if (element_children($feedback['quiz_result_answer'][$instance->result_answer_id])) {
      $questions[$question_node->nid] = array(
        '#title' => t('Question @num', array('@num' => $question['display_number'])),
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        'feedback' => $feedback,
        '#weight' => $question['number'],
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нет ничего сложного, добавить проверку и записать в переменную результат.

```
$title = "Question";
if ($question['display_number'] == 1) {
  $title = "Bla bla title";
}

'#title' => t($title . ' @num', array('@num' => $question['display_number'])),
```